# The content on disk is newer. Click on Compare to compare your version with the one on disk

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

After update to 1.19.1 I'm getting this error constantly.
**The content on disk is newer. Click on Compare to compare your version with the one on disk.**

Answer (score 39):

VS Code will show you an error message when you try to save a file that cannot be saved because it has changed on disk. VS Code blocks saving the file to prevent overwriting changes that have been made outside of the editor.

In order to resolve this issue, click the `Compare` action in the error message to open a diff editor that will show you the contents of the file on disk (to the left) compared to the contents in VS Code (on the right): {Refer an Image}

[image]

You must either accept the changes or revert the changes. Without taking any of the mentioned actions, you cant save the file.

P.S Above answer has been referred from visual studio code official documentation.

you can read detailed information about this topic: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_preventing-dirty-writes][2]

Comment: Very well explained :)

Answer (score 5):

To add to this information, v1.42 has added the ability to immediately overwrite the changes made outside of vscode or prevent the notification altogether if that is your preference.  From the release notes (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_42.md#ignore-save-conflicts):

> **Ignore save conflicts**
>
> VS Code has a built-in mechanism to show an error when you try to save
>   a dirty file that has been changed outside of VS Code or by another
>   program (for example Git):

[image: save conflict notification from release notes]

> The motivation is to inform you that saving will overwrite the
>   contents on disk even though the file was changed after the file
>   became dirty. Clicking the Compare button lets you review your change
>   along with the version on disk and either overwrite or revert the
>   file.
>
> In cases where you know that the changes on disk can be overwritten,
>   there is now an Overwrite button directly on the notification. You can
>   also configure `files.saveConflictResolution` globally or per workspace or
>   file type to disable the notification altogether.  The options are `askUser` (default) or `overwriteFileOnDisk`.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the compare button, two screens (left and right) will be displayed, click on the tick mark which appears on the right-hand side(in my case). That's it, it will be saved.

Comment: Works for me..
but before accpeting copy both contents at some place

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

1. Copy the full content of your dirty file let say abc.js to somewhere in notepad
2. Delete the file: rm abc.js
3. Get the file from the repository(my case its Git): git checkout abc.js
4. Paste the previously copied content or paste the updated content back and save.

Hope you won't see this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Close all editors, when you switch the branch in GIT, then it wouldn't appear